# Wishlist.js calling after span append Magento2

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, wishlist, magento2.2.4

```
<!-- ko if: wishlist().counter -->
        <span data-bind="text: wishlist().counter" class="counter qty"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
```

The issue I am facing is that in the file link.html, the span is getting called even if the value is null for the counter. This happens for a fraction of second, but after some time the span gets removed.

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "wishlist": {
                        "component": "Magento_Wishlist/js/view/wishlist"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `display: none;` on it with CSS (or inline `style`), then add `visible: wishlist().counter` to your data-bind.

```
<span data-bind="text: wishlist().counter, visible: wishlist().counter" class="counter qty"></span>
```

This should work as the element is not visible to begin with, and if the counter is above 0 it will display. You're seeing this 'flash' of content as it takes a while for all the Javascript to load.

This is presuming `wishlist().counter` returns a number.

Comment: Have tried using jquery the same approach, by default display none, and display after some time.